# Adding counter based on values Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, counter

I have the following DataFrame df1

```
  Id      Date                Code
   1       10/20/2018      325
   1       10/20/2018      325
   1       10/20/2028      405
```

I would like to add a counter based on all three variables so that I can join this with other DataFrame

Desired output

```
 Id      Date                Code     Counter
   1       10/20/2018      325         1
   1       10/20/2018      325         2
   1       10/20/2028      405         1
```

I tried the following

```
 df1.groupby([‘id’,’Date’,’Code’]).size()
```

It’s not giving me the desired output. Appreciate your help

Comment: have you tried `cumsum`?

Comment: cumsum is for cumulative results but what I need is just a counter based on the three values

Comment: yes, brain fart, try `cumcount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get you what you want? `cumcount` gives the cumulative count within the group for each row.

```
 df['cumcount'] = df.groupby(['Id','Date','Code']).cumcount()
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. It is just giving me Index and cumcoumt. How can I have this along with other DataFrame variables?

Comment: You can assign the results to a new column. See updated answer.